# Use a variable as an index in AMPL

Tags: ampl

I need to use a variable to identify a value of a matrix. What I wanted to do is to define a variable like:

`var a in A;  # to say that the variable takes value from index A`

and I wanted to use it as something like:

```
M1[a] >= 10;
M2[a] <= 100;
```

However AMPL complains:

*variable in index expression*

What can I point to an element of an array or matrix, using a variable?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AMPL doesn't allow variables in subscripts yet. However there is a way to emulate them. For example, `M1[a] >= 10` can be emulated as follows:

```
   s.t. c: exists{i in A} (M1[i] >= 10 and i = a);
```

This is not very efficient, but should work fine for small problems. Note that to solve a problem containing the above constraint (or variables in subscripts once they are added) requires a constraint programming solver such as [ilogcp](http://www.ampl.com/NEW/LOGIC/#ilogcp) or [gecode](http://www.ampl.com/NEW/LOGIC/#gecode). See [LOGIC AND CONSTRAINT PROGRAMMING EXTENSIONS](http://www.ampl.com/NEW/LOGIC/) for details.

New version of ilogcp driver for AMPL supports the `element` constraint, for example:

```
include cp.ampl;
var x{i in 0..2} >= i integer;
var y in 0..2 integer;
minimize o: element({i in 0..2} x[i], y);
option solver ilogcp;
solve;
```

where `element({i in 0..2} x[i], y)` is equivalent to `x[y]` and is translated into an `IloElement` constraint.

Comment: You are comparing an index to a variable, is this allowed? I will try this soon, thank you

Comment: @HAL9000 Yes, it is allowed. The set `A` should contain numbers of course.

Comment: However it seems that the only solution working with CPLEX it's to reformulate my LP as a MILP

Comment: @HAL9000 Yes, to use CPLEX you'll have to reformulate your problem. You can use ILOG/IBM CP Solver though.